# Ubuntu 20.04 lts option is not visible into bootloader after dual boot my lenovo thinkpad e490

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I was trying to dual boot my lenovo think pad e490 (8gb ram + 128gb ssd(Windows 10 pre-loaded)+1tb hhd). I shrink my 1tb hhd valume for Ubuntu installation and install Ubuntu using something else and allocate 100gb space(30gb-root, 30gb-boot, 16gb-swap & rest is for home) and successfully install Ubuntu 20.04 lt is into hhd. **But after restart system by default loading windows 10 and not showing Ubuntu option into boot loader.**
**Now what should I do to login into Ubuntu? And how to visible Ubuntu option into boot loader?**

Answer (score 0):

Do you see GRUB at all? OR just the normal Windows boot process?

How To Install Ubuntu (18.04, 19.10, 20.04) Alongside Windows 10 in Dual Boot
https://www.techsupportpk.com/2019/10/how-to-install-ubuntu-1910-alongside-windows-10-dual-boot.html

Browsing several posts like this. I suspect you are not seeing GRUB but the windows boot manager.

Comment: No I did not see Grub. It is just a normal windows boot process. Also I go through with given link and I found that, while installing Ubuntu I did not found an installation type as **Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows 10** rest two options are there and I choose **Somthing Else** from those. Did I miss somthing or I have to install both the os again?